# RegEx for a number that must contain a decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to validate a decimal number.

1. The number MUST contain a decimal point.
2. There must be one digit [0-9] to the right of the decimal point.
3. There may be max 5 digits to the left of the decimal point but they cannot start with zero unless a zero on its own.

#### Allowed:

- 0.1 (first digit can only be zero if followed by the decimal place)
- 10345.0 (max 5 digits to left of decimal place, there must be 1 digit to right of decimal place)

#### Not allowed:

- 0 (no decimal place)
- 10 (no decimal place)
- 10. (no number to the right of the decimal place)
- . (no number on either side of the decimal place)
- .1 (no number to the left of the decimal place)

This regex validates what comes before the decimal place

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,4}|0)$
```

This regex validates what comes after the decimal place

```
^[0-9]{1}+$
```

I just don't know how to combined the two such that the decimal place is mandatory.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I wanted to rule out un-necessary leading zeros (mentioned in point 3 in my original post) so 01.1 is invalid. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this works

`^(?:[1-9]\d{0,4}|0)\.\d$`

Expanded

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?:
      [1-9] \d{0,4}                 # 1-5 digits, must not start with 0
   |                              # or,
      0                             # 0
 )
 \. \d                         # decimal point and 1 digit
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This handles all my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```js
const r = /^(?:[1-9]\d{0,4}|0)\.\d+/

const arr = ['0', '1', '1.2', '1.', '1.123', '0123.1', '123.123', '1234.1', '12345.12345678', '123456.123', '0.12'];

arr.forEach((val) => {
  console.log(val, r.test(val));
})
```

Comment: Thanks felix... only thing was yours allows more than one digit after the decimal place... maybe because you have a + at the end instead of a $. Cheers!

Comment: Correct, missed that rule :]

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/YUJ1QT/1) might validate your inputs:

```
^(\d{1,5}\.\d{1,})$
```

and you can simply call it using <kbd>$1</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: It will match the invalid number `01.1`

Comment: It matches more than one digit after the decimal place as well but thank you so much for your response :)