# Regex for if a number contains a decimal point, it must have a decimal

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

There is another question, which deals with a mandatory decimal place, in this case, it is optional, and only if there are decimals. I need to check to see if a number is valid in a numeric input by comparing it to my regex on paste and keyed in. The number can contain up to 9 numbers, and if it has a decimal point, up to 6 decimal places.

For example:

123456789.123456

is a valid number, but

1234567890.1234567

or

1234567890.

is not valid. My regex thus far is:

```
/^(\d{0,9})(\.{0,1}\d{0,6})*$/
```

..but it still allows a decimal place without decimals.

[RegExr link](https://regexr.com/6neo9)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx for a number that must contain a decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856225/regex-for-a-number-that-must-contain-a-decimal-point)

Comment: It doesn't, in this case, the decimal point (and subsequent decimals) are optional.

Comment: See https://regexr.com/6nepj

Comment: So close. ^(\d{0,9})(\.\d{1,6})?$ did it. Thank you PM 77-1!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
^\d{0,9}(?:\.\d{1,6})?$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/bsTbX9/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{0,9}                  digits (0-9) (between 0 and 9 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,6}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 6 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```